# Opencart SMS on Order Creation

Tags: php, sms, opencart

I want to trigger an http API in opencart. The purpose is to send an SMS upon order creation. Should I add this code in catalog/model/checkout/order.php or elsewhere ?

I want to pass the variable of order_id to my code and get the info from the tables and pass that to the API:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM oc_order WHERE order_id='$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $name=$row["firstname"];
    $phone=$row["telephone"];
    $address=$row["payment_address_1"];
}
}
```

and then pass it on to:

```
http://api.smscompany.com/api-send-branded-sms.aspx?username=ABCD&pass=1234&text=$name,$phone,$address&masking=CompanyName&destinationnum=1234567890&language=English
```

How can I trigger the above API at the back end ? Will I need a jquery script for this ?

Comment: What is your OC version?

Comment: I am using OC 2.3.0.2